# RoR 4 - Update model with related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How I can add a model with a model related:

```
@user = User.find( cookies[:id] )
@u = @user.advert
@advert = @u.create(advert_params)
```

This model is saved correctly, but when I try to add a model related, but the property `town` is not updated

```
@user = User.find( cookies[:id] )
@u = @user.advert
@u.advert.town = Town.find(1)
@advert = @u.create(advert_params)
```

The relation between advert and town is (1 town has many adverts)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `@u.advert.town << Town.find(1)` For a future reference please give us more details like what error you're getting. Also you do not follow rails naming convention, any reason for this?

Comment: Check model errors after creating with:  `Rails.logger.info(@u.errors.full_messages.to_sentence)` and do you have `belongs_to :town` in you Advert model?

Comment: Can you show how your associations are setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@u.advert.town = Town.find(1)
```

But if, as you state:

```
@u=@user.advert
```

Then, the first line of this answer translates into

```
@user.advert.advert.town = Town.find(1)
```

You should probably do:

```
@u.town = Town.find(1)
```